# Server side and client side method

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, json

I'm using ASP.NET with C# 2.0. I have created some objects for a database and each of these objects has properties which can be called natively or are called in a similar manner and create a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) JSON API from them.

I have a lot of tab-like things I like to call 'modules' on this site - the function of a module is to convert data to HTML to be displayed on the page. Idealy this needs to be done in both server side C# code for the first tab to load, then use Ajax to load the others when the tabs are clicked, however for old browsers and search engines, the tab is still a link that will load the same HTML code server side.

Currently I've writting the JavaScript code completely separately from the C# code that converts each module to HTML, but the method is virtually the same, just a different language. Similar to this example.

**C# code**

```
public override string GetHtml()
{
    IJsonObjectCollection<Person> response = ((Village)page).People;
    string html = "<div id=\"test\">";
    foreach (Person person in response)
    {
        html += "<div class=\"person\">";
        html += person.Name;
        if(canEdit) html += "*";
        html += "</div>";
    }
    return html + "</div>";
}
```

**JavaScript code**

```
function getHtml() {
    JsonRequest('/json/villages/1/people', function(response) {
        var html = '<div id="test">';
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            var person = response[i];
            html += '<div class="person">';
            html += person.name;
            if(canEdit) html += '*';
            html += '</div>';
        }
        return html + '</div>';
    });
}
```

You can probably see where I'm going with this question. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? I was thinking of a few different alternatives -

**1.** Each ModuleToHtmlMethod could be a class that defines the method of turning this data object into HTML. I attempted this, but I stopped because I was getting too complicated.

**2.** Write my own scripting language that can be interpreted as C# but also 'compiled' into JavaScript code.

**3.** Just write the lot in C# and use Ajax to simply request the HTML content from C#

**4.** Keep the code separated and write every method twice.

I'd like to eventually allow other developers to write these 'modules', so maybe option **2** is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would discard option 4 as it will make maintenance more difficult and you may end up out of synch between the HTML generated via the Javascript and the one from the C# code. I would also discard the option 2 as that may make the code more difficult for other developers and also probably unnecessary.

I would definitely generate the HTML in one place and probably expose RESTful HTML API that uses the C# existing function to return the HTML snippets. So from your Javascript you would call:

```
function getHtml() {
    MyHtmlRequest('/html/villages/1/people', function(response) {
        var html = response.Text;
        return html;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to go. The problem here is that the majority of the code is in loops (which can be quite large), so the majority of the html would be repeated, which would dramatically increase the response size. Would gzip compression help me here?

Comment: Using gzip you should shave 50-70% of the response size, it is your call to see if that is acceptable. You should calculate the difference in Bytes between the same response using the JSON RESTful API and the HTML RESTful API. If the difference is less than 50%, gzip will certainly solve the markup overhead.

Comment: I don't need to test it to tell you it'll need to be more than 50% extra. There are loops that would usually loop round 10-20 times, but could extend to 50 odd, depending on the type of data called. Then the html code is similar to `'<div id="myrow'+i+'" class="myrow"><img src=".imgs/'+row.img+'.png" /> '+row.name+' <a href="blah" onclick="edit('+i+')">Edit</a></div>` or similar. Usually more HTML, maybe a delete button.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions.

- Have a generic GetHtml method that reflects the html.  This can be hard as UI is not something that maps easily and uniformly to data fields.
- Have a meta description of your 'modules', use this to create your generic GetHtml methods
- Finally [try this](https://github.com/gatapia/jish): It will allow you just to create JavaScript methods, you can then call them from C#

I would go for the second, meta description option as this is what I do for my data layers.  I basically have a file defining my domain model. I use this to generate all my data acccess pocos, nhibernate config files, etc.  I then have a meta data file which adds information to these objects, like UI rendering information and field validation info.

Tnx

Guido

Comment: In your second option, do you mean a human readable description that allows one to write the exact same function in many languages, or a machine readable description that could be used in a similar way to my 2nd option?

Comment: I mean a code generator.  So you define a 'description file' and then you generate all your getHtml methods.  So basically what ends up happening is you describe all your modules in a DSL (xml or json is fine, you may want to look at [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)).  So yes, its like your option 2, but its much simpler than writing your own scripting language.

Comment: Hmm.. I can see how this works with the javascript. Once it's generated C# code, do I simply copy the code into the C# code? Or will I have some fancy way of interpreting this definition, or compiling it?

Comment: Nope, you define a definition file, describing how your getHtml methods will work and then you generate both the C# and the JavaScript implementations.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't a yes/no question. I am still confused with the ambiguous terminology here.. does "you generate" mean that I have to write both or that I call something else that generates the code for me?

If it generates the C# code would I have to manually paste it in every time it changes and re-compile?

Comment: Questions been open for a while with no luck. This wasn't how I solved the issue, but it's probably the most helpful to others with similar problems, so I'll accept this answer.